# Match multiple words to replace a pattern

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed

I have a file that has data something like

```
.spec.nodes.brokers.runtime.properties.broker.http.numConnections=15
.spec.nodes.clients.runtime.properties.broker.http.numConnections=17
.spec.nodes.servers.runtime.properties.broker.http.numConnections=19
```

I want to replace `runtime.properties` by `'"runtime.properties"'`.
I can manually do multiple sed, but I wanted to see if I can get it done by one sed using pattern matching.

Also, I cannot just directly sed and replace "runtime.properties" because there are other patterns that might match this keyword. I need something that matches
`.spec.nodes.<one of brokers, clients or servers>,` 
then replace

`.spec.nodes` should only be at the start of the line, and not anywhere in the string.

Comment: So, do you want to change `runtime.properties` only if it’s *immediately* preceded by `.spec.nodes.XXXXXXs.`, or if `.spec.nodes.XXXXXXs.` appears anywhere on the same line? … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete. It’s best (a) to show expected/desired output, and (b) to include enough variation in your example input to cover all noteworthy cases (e.g., `.spec.nodes.sellers.runtime.properties.broker.http`, `.spec.nodes.brokers.foo.runtime.properties.broker.http.` and `.spec.nodes.brokers.runtime.properties.brokers.http.`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
$ cat file
.spec.nodes.brokers.runtime.properties.broker.http.numConnections=15
.spec.nodes.foo.runtime.properties.broker.http.numConnections=17
.spec.nodes.clients.runtime.properties.broker.http.numConnections=17
.spec.nodes.bar.runtime.properties.broker.http.numConnections=17
.spec.nodes.servers.runtime.properties.broker.http.numConnections=19
```

then

```
$ sed -E "/\.spec\.nodes\.(brokers|clients|servers)/s/runtime\.properties/'\"&\"'/" file
.spec.nodes.brokers.'"runtime.properties"'.broker.http.numConnections=15
.spec.nodes.foo.runtime.properties.broker.http.numConnections=17
.spec.nodes.clients.'"runtime.properties"'.broker.http.numConnections=17
.spec.nodes.bar.runtime.properties.broker.http.numConnections=17
.spec.nodes.servers.'"runtime.properties"'.broker.http.numConnections=19
```

or

```
$ sed -E '/\.spec\.nodes\.(brokers|clients|servers)/s/runtime\.properties/'\''"&"'\''/'
file
.spec.nodes.brokers.'"runtime.properties"'.broker.http.numConnections=15
.spec.nodes.foo.runtime.properties.broker.http.numConnections=17
.spec.nodes.clients.'"runtime.properties"'.broker.http.numConnections=17
.spec.nodes.bar.runtime.properties.broker.http.numConnections=17
.spec.nodes.servers.'"runtime.properties"'.broker.http.numConnections=19
```

Comment: Its working, thanks. I also need a single quotes. ```'"runtime.properties"'```Trying that out now.

Comment: This works ```sed -E '/\.spec\.nodes\.(brokers|clients|servers)/s/runtime\.properties/'"'"'"&"'"'"'/g' ```

Comment: @CSUNNY apologies, I missed that - see updated answer